# Sequelize foreign key reference composite primary key

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i'm trying to create with sequelize (postgre) 'Ingredient' table, with columns normalizedName/userId where normalizedName is unique per userId.

The second table is 'IngredientQuantity', with columns ingredientId/userId/quantity.

I tried to set in 'Ingredient' normalizedName and userId as primaryKey, and to foreign key this composite PK from 'IngredientQuantity' table with ingredientId, but i saw that was impossible with sequelize, only normalizedName is used for reference in foreign key.

Whats is the best approach to do that ? I thought about id auto increment, but all id are shared among all users. For example user1 create his first ingredient with id = 1, when user2 create his first ingredient he will have id = 2. So. i don't know if it's good idea, if all users have lot of ingredients i should use bigint etc..and if they delete/add/delete/add id will grow up.

Ingredient table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Ingredient = sequelize.define('ingredient', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        normalizedName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true },
        userId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    Ingredient.associate = function (models) {
        models.ingredient.hasMany(models.ingredientQuantity);
        models.ingredient.belongsTo(models.user, {
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    };

    return Ingredient;
};
```

IngredientQuantity table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var IngredientQuantity = sequelize.define('ingredientQuantity', {
        quantity: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    IngredientQuantity.associate = function (models) {
        models.ingredientQuantity.belongsTo(models.ingredient);
        models.ingredientQuantity.belongsTo(models.user, {
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    };

    return IngredientQuantity;
};
```

Whats is the best approach if i consider lot of data with lot of users ? Is there an other solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally normal to use `SERIAL` as autoincremented integer surrogate PK. Also you can use `UUID` as autogenerated PKs (in such case you should set default value as `uuid_generate_v4()`) if you somehow afraid that integer value range will not be enough.

Because it's a service field there is no need it to be unique only for a certain user. Usually you shouldn't rely on a PK value.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I thought that the composite primary key was the 'cleanest' solution but indeed even if I will never reach the max of the integer, the UUID is a good alternative I will go for that.